# loading pn failed in tsc build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

i have a tsc build react npm package.
And I want to use a png in my projekt.

Sadly i get an error when i try to build the projekt. Running Stroybook works fine. The Images also gets shown on the screen. Only when i try to build i reseive an error. So i think there is something wrong with the config. I Hope someone can help me fixing the config, so it will build successfully.

### ERROR

```
npm run build

> portshare-frontend-libary-components@0.1.0 build
> tsdx build

@rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`.
@rollup/plugin-replace: 'preventAssignment' currently defaults to false. It is recommended to set this option to `true`, as the next major version will default this option to `true`.
✓ Creating entry file 1.2 secs
Error: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

at D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components\src\image\placeholder.png:1:0

1: ����►JFIF☺☺☺☺,☺,��VExifMM♦☺→♣☺>☺♣☺☺(♥☺☻☻‼♥☺☺☺,☺☺,☺��,Photoshop 3.08BIM♦♦∟☺Z♥��
�http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
   ^
2: <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x='adobe:ns:meta/' x:xmptk='Image::ExifTool 10.10'>
3: <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>

PS D:\2. repo\portshare-frontend-libary-components>
```

### tsconfig

```
{
  // see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig to better understand tsconfigs
  "include": ["src", "types"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    // output .d.ts declaration files for consumers
    "declaration": true,
    // output .js.map sourcemap files for consumers
    "sourceMap": true,
    // match output dir to input dir. e.g. dist/index instead of dist/src/index
    "rootDir": "./src",
    // stricter type-checking for stronger correctness. Recommended by TS
    "strict": true,
    // linter checks for common issues
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // noUnused* overlap with @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars, can disable if duplicative
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    // use Node's module resolution algorithm, instead of the legacy TS one
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // transpile JSX to React.createElement
    "jsx": "react",
    // interop between ESM and CJS modules. Recommended by TS
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // significant perf increase by skipping checking .d.ts files, particularly those in node_modules. Recommended by TS
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // error out if import and file system have a casing mismatch. Recommended by TS
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    // `tsdx build` ignores this option, but it is commonly used when type-checking separately with `tsc`
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true, // Enable importing JSON files
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Enable synthetic default imports
    "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true, // Allow accessing UMD globals
    "types": ["node"], // Include the 'node' type definitions
    "target": "es2020",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*"],
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

### tsdx.config.js

```
const scss = require('rollup-plugin-scss');
const { default: url } = require('@rollup/plugin-url');

module.exports = {
  rollup(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      scss({
        output: true,
        sass: require('sass'),
        sassOptions: {
          includePaths: ['src'],
        },
        watch: ['src'],
      }),
      url({
        include: ['**/*.png'],
        limit: 0,
        fileName: '[name][extname]',
        destDir: options.dir, // Use options.dir to determine the destination directory
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};
```

### globals.d.ts

```
declare module '*.png';
```

### .babelrc.json

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": 100
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import"
  ]
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsdx watch",
    "build": "tsdx build",
    "test": "tsdx test --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "tsdx lint",
    "prepare": "tsdx build",
    "size": "size-limit",
    "analyze": "size-limit --why",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "tsdx lint"
    }
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  },
  "name": "portshare-frontend-libary-components",
  "author": "Leon Salenbacher",
  "module": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.esm.js",
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.cjs.production.min.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/portshare-frontend-libary-components.esm.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    }
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^8.0.1",
    "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "^8.2.4",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.21",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "portshare-frontend-libary-objects": "^1.0.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.13.0",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "size-limit": "^8.2.4",
    "storybook": "^7.0.21",
    "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^5.1.7",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```